# Abbreviate vector of names in R, using stringr library

Tags: r

I have this variable:

```
names<-c("Sophia Abbe", "Olivia Abbett", "Emma Abbey", "Ava Abbitt", "Isabella Abbot", "Mia Abbott", "Aria Abbs")
```

I want to abbreviate the first names and place them into a vector.

I want to obtain a vector like ("S. Abbe", "O. Abbett", ... , "A. Abbs)

What would be an efficient way of doing this with the stringr functions str_c(), str_split() and str_sub() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `sub` by matching the lower case letters and replace with a `.` in `base R`

```
sub("[a-z]+", ".", names)
#[1] "S. Abbe"   "O. Abbett" "E. Abbey"  "A. Abbitt" "I. Abbot"  "M. Abbott" "A. Abbs"
```

In this the `[a-z]+` matching one or more lower blocks of characters i.e. those in the first word (because we are using `sub`) and replace with `""`

Or using `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(names, "[a-z]+", ".")
```

Comment: Could you please explain how "[a-z]+" works in this context?